# use find to delete all but last file within subdirectories

Tags: find, delete

I want to free up some space by deleting redundant files within many subdirectories. However I always want to retain the last file of a file stem. For example I have an assortment (next to other files that should not be touched) similar to this:

`FILE_1-1
 FILE_1-2
 FILE_1-3
 FILE_2-1
 FILE_2-2`

within a whole bunch of branching subdirectories. I want to keep `FILE_2-2` in this instance, but in another folder it would be `FILE_3-1` or whatever. Always the last file. I know how to get rid of all of them using the find command which traverses the subdirectories nicely:

`find . -name "FILE_*" -type f -delete`

**How can I exclude the last `FILE_*` within each directory where removal happens using the find command?** Googling (https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/36639-find-remove-all-but-latest-file.html) turned up the following:

`ls -1 FILE_* | sort -r | tail +2 |  xargs -i rm {}`

But this command does not work with branching directories, does it?

Comment: to make matters worse, you'll also need to worry about the `sort` functionality if you have more than one digit in the sequence.  `FILE_1-10` comes lexicographically _before_ `FILE_1-2` .  Padding with zeros (eg `FILE_1-002` ) would make numeric and lexicographic order consistent.

Comment: For a general answer, yes. In my case the highest number is fortunately ``FILE_3-5``. I hope this helps to keep it simple.

Comment: You mention branching subdirectories, but they need to be considered when finding "the last file", or is the "last file" the one in each separate subdirectory?

Comment: There's a slight inconsistency; your example command shows `ls ... FILE_*.txt` while your sample filenames do not end in `.txt`

Comment: You are correct, I edited that out. And It's always the last file within each separate subdirectory.

Answer (score 1):

In a directory you can find the "stems" with:

```
ls * | sed -r 's/[0-9]+$//' | sort | uniq
```

For each stem you can list all files with the last with:

```
ls  FILE_1-* | head -n -1
```

Or if you want to keep the most recent:

```
ls -rt FILE_1-* | head -n -1
```

Both commands can be followed by `| xargs rm` to delete their output

Put all that in a short script(*) and run:

```
find . -type d -exec {the_script} {} \;
```

(*) the short script would look like:

```
#! /bin/bash
cd "$1"  # takes the directory as a parameter
for stem in $(ls FILE* | sed -r 's/[0-9]+$//' | sort | uniq)
do 
    ls -rt ${stem}* | head -n -1 | xargs echo rm 
done
```

Of course test thoroughly and replace `echo rm` by just `rm` when you are confident that it will erase the right files.

Comment: I put the first and the third line into the script and then executed the last line and I'm getting the error ``find: ‘{the_script}’: No such file or directory``. I put the script into the parent folder where I am executing the find command. What do I do wrong?

Comment: `{the script}` is of course a place holder for your actual script name. Note that your script is also assumed to loop over the stems:  line 3 is executed once for each stem found with line 1.

Comment: Added sample script, use at your own risk.